# ROracle dbWriteTable affirms insertion that didnt happen

Tags: r, roracle

My goal is to create a table in the database and fill it with data afterwards. This is my code:

```
library(ROracle)

# ... "con" is the connection string, created in an earlier stage!

# 1 create example
testdata <- data.frame(A = c(1,2,3), B = c(4,5,6))
# 2 create-statement
createTable <- paste0("CREATE TABLE TestTable(", paste(paste(colnames(testdata), c("integer", "integer")), collapse = ","), ")")
# 3 send and execute query
dbGetQuery(con, createTable)
# 4 write example data
dbWriteTable(con, "TestTable", testdata, row.names = TRUE, append = TRUE)
```

I already suceeded a few times. The table was created and filled.

Now step 4 doesn't work anymore, R returns TRUE after execution of `dbWriteTable` though. But the table is still empty.

I know this is a vague question, but does anyone have an idea what could be wrong here?

Comment: I don't think this is a vague question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution for my problem. After creating the table in step 3, you have to commit! After that, the data is written into the table.

```
library(ROracle)

# ... "con" is the connection string, created in an earlier stage!
# 1 create example
testdata <- data.frame(A = c(1,2,3), B = c(4,5,6))
# 2 create-statement
createTable <- paste0("CREATE TABLE TestTable(", paste(paste(colnames(testdata), c("integer", "integer")), collapse = ","), ")")
# 3 send and execute query
dbGetQuery(con, createTable)
# NEW LINE: COMMIT!
dbCommit(con)
# 4 write example data
dbWriteTable(con, "TestTable", testdata, row.names = TRUE, append = TRUE)
```